# How to load jQuery BEFORE bootstrap.js under Sails.js v0.12 without linker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, sails.js

As You know, Sails v0.1X no more need for --linker. In this case, so how can i let in Gruntfile.js to load jQuery before bootstrap.js is loaded?

Comment: Your question isn't terribly clear. I would suggest reading [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then returning here to make things a more easily understood

Comment: What exactly is unclear in my q.?

Comment: 2 lines of text doesn't tell us alot. Review the link I posted to get a better understanding of how to make questions clear and answerable.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a particular order to load your assets inside the `tasks/pipeline.js` file:

```
// Client-side javascript files to inject in order
// (uses Grunt-style wildcard/glob/splat expressions)
var jsFilesToInject = [

  // Load sails.io before everything else
  'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',

  // Load jQuery before Bootstrap and other libraries
  'js/dependencies/jquery.js',
  'js/dependencies/bootstrap.js',

  // Dependencies are brought in here
  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',

  // All of the rest of your client-side js files
  // will be injected here in no particular order.
  'js/**/*.js'
];
```